# Equivalente en español de "bath" vs "shower"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, inglés, guatemala

En inglés, se distingue claramente entre el uso de:

> I'm going to take a shower.

Contra:

> I'm going to take a bath.

El primero es un baño diario rápido, regular, con regadera solamente.  El segundo es un baño en una tina llena de agua, usualmente tibia o caliente, para relajarse, y que a veces se asocia con un spa.

A pesar de estar viviendo ya por años en Estados Unidos, aún cometo el error de decir *I'm going to take a bath*, porque el equivalente en español es simplemente *Me voy a tomar un baño*. Ante esto, la mayoría de personas se asombran, y me tardo unos segundos en darme cuenta y corregir lo dicho.

Pensando si existe algún equivalente, lo único que pude encontrar que fuera similar a *shower* en español sería algo como *regaderazo*, que usamos en Guatemala coloquialmente.

¿Existe en español alguna mejor palabra, o forma de decir esto?

Comment: Sugerencia práctica para no crear dudas en inglés: "I'm going to bathe."  (Rima con *lathe*.)  Ya que este verbo es equivalente a "bañarme" -- sirve para los dos métodos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En España no utilizamos la palabra *regadera* más que para designar el artilugio para regar las plantas, o para decir *estás como una regadera* (*estás loco*). Eso sí, por contexto se entendió rápido a lo que te referías (y el DLE recoge en [*regadera*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VgOoyu6)).

Siguiendo con los usos de España, la traducción directa, usual y que todo el mundo entendería de *take a shower* es ***darse una ducha***.

> [**ducha**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EDzFAGf%7CEE04fOi)
>   Del fr. douche, y este del it. doccia 'caño de agua'.
>   1. f. Acción y efecto de duchar.
>   2. f. Proyección de agua que, en forma de lluvia o de chorro, se hace caer en el cuerpo para limpiarlo o refrescarlo, o con propósito medicinal.
>   3. f. Aparato o instalación que sirve para ducharse.
>   4. f. Recipiente de loza u otra materia donde se recogen las aguas de la ducha.
>   5. f. Habitación o lugar donde hay una ducha.
>   6. f. Arg., Bol. y Par. Cuarto de aseo con ducha, sin bañera.

Como ves, la palabra sirve para muchas cosas a la vez: la acción, el aparato, la habitación y el recipiente. Sin embargo, *darse una ducha* se entiende automáticamente y no tiene ningún género de dudas.

Comment: Y además darse un baño se entiende como meterse en una bañera (o en una piscina o el mar) pero nunca como ducharse.